# How do I get number from this format:,[[5,["95",1,"#ffffff"]]]], using regex

Tags: php, regex

I have a string like this:

```
",[[3,"bus.png",null,"Bus",[["https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/transit/iw2/b/bus.png",0,[15,15],null,0]]]],[[null,null,null,null,"0x31da18325b415901:0xeb661015c651c24a",[[5,["48",1,"#ffffff"]]]],[null,null,null,null,"0x31da19f34e04d59b:0x5758ef6990938b",[[5,["61",1,"#ffffff"]]]],[null,null,null,null,"0x31da1a5b8b75c379:0x6a13e189555f9fab",[[5,["95",1,"#ffffff"]]]],[null,null,null,null,"0x31da1a16ea23bf95:0xd7c90f15535c2b9f",[[5,["106",1,"#ffffff"]]]],[null,null,null,null,"0x31da10a7613d616f:0xf1f61ffeac2ea8a4",[[5,["970",1,"#ffffff"]]]],[null,null,null,null,"0x31da1a0bd6262d0b:0xfbd5d2bfd7a1252",[[5,["NR8",1,"#ffffff"]]]]],null,0,"5"]]],["http://www
```

I need to get all the numbers: "48, 61,95,106,970,NR8"; so basically, need to process this format :`"48, 61,95,106,970,NR8"`
I tried:

```
function get_numbers_from($input) {
    $matches = preg_match_all('(\[\"[]a-zA-Z0-9]*?\"\,\d*?\,\".*?\"\])', $input);
    foreach($matches[1] as $key => $match) {
        array_push($numbers, explode(',', $match)[0]);
    }

    return $numbers;
}
```

But seems it shows:  `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`
How to correct it?

Comment: Use [`\["([A-Z]*\d+)"`](https://regex101.com/r/mY5pT0/1)

Comment: I tried: $matches = preg_match_all('(\["([A-Z]*\d+)")', $input); but same error

Comment: i posted together with code demo and pattern explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the manual for `preg_match_all()`, the function returns a boolean. And you use the third parameter for the matches.

Also you can change your regex to this one:

```
\[\[\d+,\[\"(\w+)\",\d+,"#[\da-fA-F]+"]]]]
```

To get the number directly from it without `explode()`, e.g.

```
function get_numbers_from($input) {
    preg_match_all('/\[\[\d+,\[\"(\w+)\",\d+,"#[\da-fA-F]+"]]]]/', $input, $matches);

    return $matches[1];
}
```

Comment: I got this error :"Warning: preg_match_all(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 7" and it not showing the result using echo

Comment: @user1314404 Little copy error, forgot to add the delimiters `/` around the regex. Fixed now.

Comment: Can you print out all the numbers as I tried using explode?

Comment: @user1314404 Do you mean `implode()`? E.g. `echo implode(",", $matches[1]);`

Comment: The result like this: array(6) { [0]=> string(2) "48" [1]=> string(2) "61" [2]=> string(2) "95" [3]=> string(3) "106" [4]=> string(3) "970" [5]=> string(3) "NR8" } ; how could I get number 48,95, 106, 970, NR8

Comment: @user1314404 Yes you want to use `implode()` as I showed above.

Comment: Yes, that's perfect answer! Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
'~\["([A-Z]*\d+)"~'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mY5pT0/1) and the [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/XYBiGl)

```
$re = '~\["([A-Z]*\d+)"~'; 
$str = "\",[[3,\"bus.png\",null,\"Bus\",[[\"https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/transit/iw2/b/bus.png\",0,[15,15],null,0]]]],[[null,null,null,null,\"0x31da18325b415901:0xeb661015c651c24a\",[[5,[\"48\",1,\"#ffffff\"]]]],[null,null,null,null,\"0x31da19f34e04d59b:0x5758ef6990938b\",[[5,[\"61\",1,\"#ffffff\"]]]],[null,null,null,null,\"0x31da1a5b8b75c379:0x6a13e189555f9fab\",[[5,[\"95\",1,\"#ffffff\"]]]],[null,null,null,null,\"0x31da1a16ea23bf95:0xd7c90f15535c2b9f\",[[5,[\"106\",1,\"#ffffff\"]]]],[null,null,null,null,\"0x31da10a7613d616f:0xf1f61ffeac2ea8a4\",[[5,[\"970\",1,\"#ffffff\"]]]],[null,null,null,null,\"0x31da1a0bd6262d0b:0xfbd5d2bfd7a1252\",[[5,[\"NR8\",1,\"#ffffff\"]]]]],null,0,\"5\"]]],[\"http://www\n48, 61,95,106,970,NR8"; 
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

The pattern matches:

- `\[` - a `[`
- `"` - a quote
- `([A-Z]*\d+)`  - Group 1: any uppercase ASCII letter, 0 or more times, followed with 1 or more digits
- `"` - a quote

The value you need is located inside the `$matches[1]` variable. It holds all the values captured with the parenthesized subpattern (Group 1).

Comment: Depending on what the prefix can be before the digits, you can adjust `[A-Z]` character class.